# FCM token in flutter, working fine in Android devices but not on iOS. Anyone know why?

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using a pretty straightforward code to get the FCM token for a device. Its working well on Android but not on iOS. I have generated an APN key and add it to my Firebase too. Is there something I am missing?

```
// Automatic imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<String?> gettingFirebaseId() async {
  try {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    // Request permission to receive notifications
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    switch (settings.authorizationStatus) {
      case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
      case AuthorizationStatus.provisional:
        prefs.setBool('hasRequestedNotificationPermission', true);
        print('Notification Permission Granted');
        break;
      case AuthorizationStatus.denied:
        print('Notification Permission Denied');
        break;
      case AuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        print('Notification Permission Not Determined');
        break;
    }

    // Attempt to get the device token regardless of the permission status
    String? token = await messaging.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      print('FCM Token: $token');
    } else {
      print('Failed to retrieve FCM Token');
    }
    return token;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error getting FCM Token: $e');
    return "fcm_token_not_found";
  }
}
```

I cant afford a Mac and dont have xCode and unable to debug on Android Studio. I am not sure how to debug this. The FCM token is being returned and notifications working fine on Android

Comment: You need Xcode to create certificates and upload it in the firebase with the registered bundle identifier. And need to enable push notification capabilities in Xcode.